# MySQL Query isn't printing all table data

Tags: php, mysql

Probably a simple solution here, but here is my code:

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY name");
$info = mysql_fetch_array($data);
?>
```

and then printing it with:

```
<select>
 <?php
  while($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
     echo '<option value="'.$info['value'].'" rel="'.$info['del'].'">'.$info['name'].'</option>';
  }
 ?>
</select>
```

For some reason it's returning all results except for the very first one? Ex. I'm ordering by name and the first one should be Apples (id = 9), but it's skipping that and returning Blueberries (id = 5)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: I'm guessing that the initial value is getting consumed. Try removing the first "$info = mysql_fetch_array($data);"

Comment: thank you @Matt for that link! I'll definitely read about that, and thanks Greg for the reply, you were also correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `mysql_fetch_array()` immediately after `mysql_query()` before your loop, which retrieves one row into `$info` and advances the record pointer to the second row. When you then enter your fetch loop, the rowset is already pointing to the second row.

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY name");
// Don't do this!
// $info = mysql_fetch_array($data);
// Instead just proceed with your while loop to fetch rows...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY name");
$info = mysql_fetch_array($data);
```

That first mysql_fetch_array line loads a row of data; when you go into the for loop, that then loads the next row, so the first row is discarded.

The easiest solution is just to remove that first call.

Comment: thanks for the quick comment, same answer as Michael, worked!